# Low energy continuous model to lattice model(tight binding) in solid physics state

Tags: solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, lattice-model, tight-binding

It is widely employed to link the low-energy continuous model to lattice tight-binding model using this strategy as shown in Section IIA Page.1063 of [RMP 83, 1057](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.83.1057) :

Just replace $k_i$ by using $\frac{\sin{k_i a_i}}{a_i}$ and replace $k_i^2$ by using $\frac{4}{a_i^2}\sin^2{\frac{k_i a_i}{2}}$.

However, some continuous models include $\mathbf{k}^3$, such as the warping term $\mathbf{k_\pm}^3$ in Bi$_2$Se$_3$ [PRL. 103, 266801](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.266801), with $\mathbf{k_\pm}=k_x\pm i k_y$.

My question is how to transfer the $\mathbf{k}^3$ term in continuous models into lattice models.